# Docker - Golang cannot find package

Tags: docker, go

I have an application using Golang, I want to "dockerize" it, base on [this tutorial](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-docker-tutorial/)
Here is the project structure:
[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.12.7-alpine3.9
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

When I try to run this command:

```sh
docker build -t pln-monitoring .
```

It shows this error:

```sh
Step 5/6 : RUN go build -o main .
 ---> Running in 5e3c84f1435d
main.go:12:2: cannot find package "github.com/geshtng/pln-monitoring/middleware" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/geshtng/pln-monitoring/middleware (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/github.com/geshtng/pln-monitoring/middleware (from $GOPATH)
main.go:13:2: cannot find package "github.com/geshtng/pln-monitoring/pkg/common/config" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/geshtng/pln-monitoring/pkg/common/config (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/github.com/geshtng/pln-monitoring/pkg/common/config (from $GOPATH)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it failed because the dependencies used by golang program are not available inside docker for it to build successfully.

You are using dep for dependency management i.e. for your external libraries locally but have not installed any of them in the docker.

You need to have them available in docker by having first dep tool within your container. The dep tool will ensure that your dependencies required by the package are available by `dep ensure`

Also, you should ideally put your repository in the $GOPATH as mentioned below

The dockerfile will need these commands:

```
FROM golang:1.12 
RUN mkdir /go/src/app
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep

ADD ./main.go /go/src/app
COPY ./Gopkg.toml /go/src/app

WORKDIR /go/src/app 

RUN dep ensure 
RUN go build
CMD ["./app"]
```

It may be also useful for you to read about Go Modules and differences with `dep` [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/switch-to-go-modules-from-go-dep-fcdd4aa41bd5)

Comment: When I run the same command using your `Dockerfile`, it says error `go: missing Git command.`
I have move my project to outside `GOPATH` (now using module)

Comment: I think that's because of use of alpine image. Use the updated code